# Google appengine, ndb, and Json

Tags: json, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have an attribute that I'm storing as a JSON object, like so:

```
content  = ndb.JsonProperty()
```

When I do this, I get this error:

```
   line 1614, in _to_base_type
    return json.dumps(value, 2)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dumps'
```

inside the ndb model class.

As a `ndb.TextProperty` it works properly.  Maybe I'm sending the JSON wrong, this is the JSON object I'm sending:

```
{posttext: "What is your earliest memory of WWII?", linkdata: ""}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you perhaps have a module named 'json.py' or a package named 'json' in your app?  That would override the json module that ndb is trying to import.  The solution is to pick a different name for that module or package.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing works fine when I try it:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
class TestModel(ndb.Model):
  foo = ndb.JsonProperty()
t = TestModel(foo={"posttext": "What is your earliest memory of WWII?", "linkdata": ""})
t.put()
Key('TestModel', 7001)
```

Can you go into more detail about exactly how you're doing this? How does it differ from the snippet above?